# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity in Blazor UserManager and RoleManager always null

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor-server-side

I am trying to get a users Roles after they log in via Single Sign On. The problem is that the UserManager and RoleManager objects are always null.  From what I have read online, is seems like these objects should be created via injection, but I am not sure what I am doing wrong.  Here is my code (if I am missing anything relevant, please let me know and I will edit my question).  I also did not see a tag for "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" so apologies if this is not tagged correctly (the error is in the last function "TransformClaims"):

**Startup.cs**

```
 using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

 public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
 {
   //.....
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
  //.....
 }
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   //.....
   services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
      options.UseSqlServer(
         Configuration.GetConnectionString("ApplicationDbContextConnection")));
            
   services.AddIdentity<CustomUserContext, IdentityRole>(options =>    options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
   services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options => 
   options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);

   services.AddRazorPages();
   services.AddServerSideBlazor();
   services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<CustomUserContext>>();
   services.AddAuthorizationCore();
    ConfigureSSO(services);    
   services.AddTransient<UserManager<USAIDUserContext>>();
   services.AddTransient<ApplicationDbContext>();
   //.....
}

public void ConfigureSSO(IServiceCollection services){
  //code to provide SSO
  //relevant code is when SSO returns token validation
  OnTokenValidated = async ctxt =>
     {
        Trace.TraceInformation("Token validated");
         ctxt.Properties.IsPersistent = true;
         ctxt.Properties.IssuedUtc = DateTime.Now;
         ctxt.Properties.ExpiresUtc = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1);

          ClaimsPrincipal claimPrinciple = ctxt.Principal;
          ClaimsIdentity ClaimsID = await TransformClaims(claimPrinciple);
          await Task.Yield();
     },

 }
private async Task<ClaimsIdentity> TransformClaims(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            ClaimsIdentity appIdentity = null;
            if(principal == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(principal));
            }
            else
            {
                //gets loggedin email, which is stored in database
                var loggedInUserId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "email")?.Value;
                RoleManager<IdentityRole> _rolemanager;
                UserManager<CustomUserContext> _userManager;
                
                //both RoleManager and UserManager are null, causing the functions below to have an error about object being null
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(loggedInUserId);                
                var roles = await _userManager.GetRolesAsync(user);
            }

            return appIdentity;
        }
```

**Edit**

**AddRolesClaimsTransformation.cs**

```
public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public AddRolesClaimsTransformation(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            // Code Never Hit
            var clone = principal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

            // Support AD and local accounts
            var nameId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier ||
                                                              c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (nameId == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }    
            // Get user from database
            var userResponse = await _userService.GetAsync(nameId.Value);         
            return clone;
        }
    }
    public interface IUserService
    {
        Task<USAIDUserContext> GetAsync(string id);            
    }
}
```

Comment: Where do you _inject_ RoleManager and UserManager?
You should inject in the `IClaimsTransformation` implemented class.

Comment: @NicolaBiada  Thanks, That might be what I am missing.  Do you have an example of how that is done or know of a tutorial that covers that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is my implementation, you can find the constructor of the class that implement the interface.

I've injected IUserService and inside the constructor of UserService class I've added injection for UserManager and RoleManager.

```
public class AddRolesClaimsTransformation : IClaimsTransformation
    {
        private readonly IUserService _userService;

        public AddRolesClaimsTransformation(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsPrincipal principal)
        {
            // Clone current identity
            var clone = principal.Clone();
            var newIdentity = (ClaimsIdentity)clone.Identity;

            // Support AD and local accounts
            var nameId = principal.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier ||
                                                              c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
            if (nameId == null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            // Get user from database
            var userResponse = await _userService.GetAsync(nameId.Value);
            if (!userResponse.Succeeded || userResponse.Data is null)
            {
                return principal;
            }

            var user = userResponse.Data;
            var rolesResponse = await _userService.GetRolesAsync(user.Id);

           ...

            return clone;
        }
    }
```

This is an example of a method inside **UserService**:

```
public async Task<IResult<UserResponse>> GetAsync(string userId)
        {
            var user = await _userManager.Users.Where(u => u.Id.ToString() == userId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
            var result = _mapper.Map<UserResponse>(user);
            return await Result<UserResponse>.SuccessAsync(result);
        }
```

Comment: I tried your recommendation, but could not find a way that it would address my issue.  I am trying to use the UserManager and RoleManager in the Startup.cs file.  But, I found that I could inject them into the Configure method.  That kind of works, but causes issues with Async.  I added additional notes in my question, if you are able to assist in recommending how to fix that?

Comment: Don't use DI in _Configure_ to use UserManager or RoleManager, instead create a separate service, as in my example, and use dependency injector there via constructor.

Comment: OK, I'll take another look.  I am not very familiar with C# and services, so I am having a  hard time figuring out how to use IUserService.

Comment: Hello, I have added the example you provided in my code.  But, the TransformAsync function is never called.  I have tried registering this with ConfigureServices, in Startup.cs, but get an error on startup, in Program.cs that says "Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.IAuthenticationService Lifetime: Scoped ImplementationType: "

Comment: Turns out the issue was a problem with how I injected this into Startup.cs ConfigureServices.  Even though I had "services.AddScoped<IClaimsTransformation, ApplicationUserClaimsTransformation>();" it was not in the right order.  Once I placed this and cleaned up unused services I was injecting, which I did not need, this worked.